# Google Sheets : Flatten row of Cell References to String in a getpivotdata

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a Sheet that tracks employee hours and maps them to wage spending. I'm importing data from our hours tracking software, into Page 2 which has aggregates the data into a Pivot Table. Then I'm using that Pivot Table as the basis for one master table on a Page 1 (which aggregates other information as well).

My problem is that we're adding people every other month, and the cell references that I'm using (so that I can fill the first box manually and drag it down to fill out the rest of the cells each month) keeps changing, and I'm finding it cumbersome to go through and manually change each cell reference to name. For instance:

`=getpivotdata("SUM of Hours",  'Hours Data'!$A$1, "Date - Month", "Jan", "First Name", **'Hours Data'!A1**)`

changes to

`=getpivotdata("SUM of Hours",  'Hours Data'!$A$1, "Date - Month", "Feb", "First Name", **"John"**)`

Is there some algorithmic way or possibly a hotkey to change a cell reference to the string that it references?

In other words, is there an easy way to change a whole row of references like this from "'Hours Data'!U14" to "Elliot"?
[I want to flatten a whole row of references like this to "Elliot", and the next row to "John" etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ge3p.png)

Or is my only path forward here to just bite the bullet and change 120+ references to a name manually each month?

I've tried googling around for "flatten reference to string" to no avail. I've tried looking through the Google Sheets hotkey documentation.

Thank you!